# Acrobat Reader DC fails on CommandInvalidContextError when submitting PDF document to server

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

We have Flex application that opens the `PDF` document in `IFRAME` and allows user to fill-in the `PDF` form, add signature and submit the `PDF` back to the server.

HTML fragment:

```
<object CLASSID="clsid:CA8A9780-280D-11CF-A24D-444553540000" id="myPdf" border="0" width="100%" height="100%"
    type="application/pdf"
    standby="Loading pdf..."> 
    <PARAM NAME="src" VALUE="downloadDocument.do?docId=12345">
    <p>Error Loading PDF.</p>
</object>
```

When user submits the `PDF` back to the server following JavaScript code is executed.

```
function submitPdf(url) {
    var params = new Array(3);
    params[0] = "Submit";
    params[1] = url;
    params[2] = "PDF";
    var ar = document.getElementById("myPdf");
    ar.messageHandler = {
        onMessage : function(msg) {
            window.alert("Success...");
        },
        onError : function(error, msg) {
            window.alert(error);
        }
    };

    ar.execCommand(params);
}
```

URL is the server-side handler which receives `PDF` data and saves it to the database. Client is already logged to the application and has valid `JSESSIONID` cookie.

Everything works with Acrobat Reader 10, but after installation of newest Acrobat Reader 2015 DC we get `CommandInvalidContextError` exception.

Does anyone know what needs to be done to get the submit action working or how to call Acrobat Reader plugin's API properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to **update to the latest build of Adobe Reader DC** (In application main menu -> Help -> Check for updates)

In June 2015 was released update 2015.008.20082. This continuous update provides security mitigations, and bug fixes. It's possible that your problem is related with this release notes.

I hope that this solution will be included in next major update in base installation.